# Connection could not be established with host ssl://smtp.mail.ru:465

Tags: php, laravel, email, ssl, smtp

Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.mail.ru:465": stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`relay.v.fozzy.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.mail.ru'

my .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.ru
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@mail.ru
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=secret@mail.ru
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

What can you help me do. Thank you.

Comment: I think, you need to change your hosting.

Comment: try add ``MAIL_MAILER=smtp``  to your .env